# Setup issue in CAS Server in Rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubycas, rubycas-server, rubycas-client

I have installed `rubyCAS Server` on ec2 server, using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3 and configured `configure.yml` file, my

```
server: webrick
port: 9292
ssl_cert: /mnt/rubyonrails/testingcas.pem
```

Note: 
I have mentioned Domain name `fortestingonly.managemyasc.devserver` during generate self signed SSL'

```
database:
adapter: mysql2
database: casserver
username: root
password: XXXXX
host: localhost
reconnect: true

authenticator:
class: CASServer::Authenticators::SQL
database:
adapter: mysql2
database: mmx_dev
username: root
password: XXXXX
host: localhost
user_table: userdemo
username_column: username
password_column: password
```

And  i have also mapped cas server url in my local `/etc/host` as `184.72.242.142       fortestingonly.managemyasc.devserver`

And in Environment file: `:cas_base_url => "https://fortestingonly.managemyasc.devserver:9292"`

Now I have fired up Rubycas server and my Application server but As I tried to access my application URL, getting following error in my application log:

```
Started GET "/" for 122.162.49.205 at 2014-01-31 04:01:14 -0800
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
Guessed service url: "http://ohio-ortho.managemyasc.devserver:3000/"
Generated login url: https://fortestingonly.managemyasc.devserver:9292/login?             service=http%3A%2F%2Fohio-ortho.managemyasc.devserver%3A3000%2F
Redirecting to "https://fortestingonly.managemyasc.devserver:9292/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fohio-ortho.managemyasc.devserver%3A3000%2F"
Redirected to https://fortestingonly.managemyasc.devserver:9292/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fohio-ortho.managemyasc.devserver%3A3000%2F
Filter chain halted as CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Oink Action: dashboard#index
Memory usage: 779472 | PID: 29159
Instantiation Breakdown: Total: 1 | ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session: 1
Oink Log Entry Complete
```

Comment: Is that really an error, looks like its redirecting you to the cas server to perform auth?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recently set up [CASino](http://casino.rbcas.com/) (also a Ruby-based CAS server), and it was quite effortless.  You might want to give it a go, if you're not sold on rubyCAS.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not an error as @MatthewFord pointed out.

Second, this redirecting is happening due to the in-built and default functionalities of the CAS server and you can think of this as a pre-configured web server just like scaffolding.

Third, in order to rectify this redirection, you need to check in the `routes.rb` file and the routing files related to the web server containg routing filters and somewhere `\` is being redirected.

Fourth, if this also not works, then this issue might be due to the `SSL Certificate` configuration. SSL Certificate configuration is often responsible for this kind of `root` redirection by the web server.